# How to increase font size of Goto Symbol in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to increase the font size of the **Goto Symbol** (`Ctrl+R`) panel.

I tried Boxy Configuration *Quick Panels > Quick Panel Size > Medium* but still no use.

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-3-increase-goto-symbol-font-size/10426/7

The same problem as in the above url. I also want to increase the size of the font in **Goto Anything** file url (the url that is displayed below the filename when we try to search for files).

Answer (score 2):

try to add the following to your theme

```
     {
        "class": "quick_panel_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "mini_quick_panel_row"}],
        "font.size": 20
     },
```